# Socket.io how to leave the room

Tags: node.js, socket.io

for some reason my code does not work, when the user leaves the room. Console says that room has been left but the connection is not lost. Down below are chunks of my code:

Client-side

```js
router
  .on({
    '/': () => {
      router.navigate(`/`);
      socket.emit('leaveRoom');
      showStartModalWindow();
    },
    '/:room': () => {
      hideStartModalWindow();
    },
  })
  .resolve();
```

Backend/server-side

```js
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('a user connected');

  socket.on('create', ({ room, name }) => {
    room = joinRoom(room, socket);
    console.log(`a room ${room} has been created`);
    console.log(`user name is ${name}`);

    socket.on('leaveRoom', () => {
      socket.leave(room);
      console.log(`the room ${room} has been left`);
    });

    //...

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
      console.log('user disconnected');
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I don't know the more elegant way to leave the room than just emit disconnection and then emit connection, when a user on the room page.
Client-side code

```js
router
  .on({
    '/': () => {
      router.navigate(`/`);
      socket.emit('leaveRoom');
      showStartModalWindow();
    },
    '/:room': () => {
      hideStartModalWindow();
      socket.connect();
    },
  })
  .resolve();
```

Backend/server-side code

```js
socket.on('leaveRoom', () => {
  socket.disconnect();
  console.log(`user ${socket.id} has left room ${room}`);
});
```